# Исправить UTF-8 (отображаются коды: I=E2=80=99m) в Python

Tags: python, utf-8, unicode, кодировка

Есть текст, в котором вместо символов используются их коды (неправильно видимо конвертировались). Итого имею: `I=E2=80=99m` вместо `I'm`. Как с помощью Python можно исправить это?

Comment: контекст: текст из e-mail? См. quopri модуль

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Change "Quoted-printable" encoding to "utf-8"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14249288/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте вставленный модул [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/quopri.html) для декодирования на *последовательность байтов*, затем интерпретируйте эту последовательность байтов как *строку в UTF-8*:

```
import quopri

temporary_bytes  = quopri.decodestring('I=E2=80=99m')
converted_string = temporary_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print(converted_string)      # Только для теста
```

Вывод:

> ```
> I’m
> ```

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что если строка это часть e-mail, то может быть удобней email пакет использовать, не ковыряясь руками внутри содержимого e-mail самостоятельно.